# INPUT_GET doesn't work with some strings?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I'm encountering a situation I can't figure out and passing along a string from javascript to PHP via jquery. Simply put when I have a `y+` it doesn't seem to pass from javascript to PHP, but when it says `y-` it does pass. Here is a code for the HTML.

This happens if I type in any math expression that starts with `y+`. It also happens if it starts with `x+`. If I change the equation around in anyways as to the string being passed it works unless it starts with one of those two. I've looked at how input_get works but can't find any limitations on the plus sign, similar to how you have to be careful with things like quotes or . I figure there is something like this which is stopping the string from being passed along.

Javascript side:

```js
function initResults(data) {
    document.getElementById("test").innerHTML=data;     
}

function init() {
    var equation=document.getElementById("username").value;
    $.get("test.php",{equation: equation},initResults);
}
```

PHP side:

```php
$equation=filter_input(INPUT_GET,"equation");  
print"$equation from php file";
```

There are no error messages, it just doesn't pass. Below is two screenshots first where it works, the other where it doesn't. I've typed in multiple examples on what works and what doesn't work which I included in the third screenshot. Thanks!

Comment: the `+` sign is commonly used in querystrings ( GET ) - perhaps use POST instead

Comment: try encoding the string before it is sent to PHP (using **htmlentities** function) and inside PHP then decode the string (using **html_entity_decode** function).